# Ativar e desativar um evento sem precisar excluir e recriar o mesmo

Tags: javascript, jquery

Há algum modo de desativar e ativar um evento existente num objeto?

Exemplo, tenho um evento num elemento `<img onclick="foo();">`

Nessa mesma página, há uma ação onde, enquanto em execução, precisa impedir que o usuário execute eventos de outros objetos.

Para isso, ao executar tal evento, todos os outros são desativados.

O problema é que não encontro nada na documentação do JQuery referente a isso.

O único meio é apagar o evento dos outros objetos e quando precisar ativá-los novamente é preciso fazer de novo a criação desses eventos.

Dessa forma funciona bem, porém, eu acho que poderia existir algo mais econômico como um simples "enable", "disable".

Estou usando Jquery, porém, se existir uma forma de resolver diretamente pelo JavaScript, obviamente é bastante válido.

Pensei que desativando o objeto, isso funcionaria, porém, não funciona. Mesmo com o objeto setado como "disabled", os eventos persistem normalmente.

Exemplo:

```
<img id="bar" onclick="foo();">


/*
Tentei com attr() e prop(). Ambos não surtem efeito.
*/
//$('#bar').prop('disabled',true);
$('#bar').attr('disabled',true);
```

Quando clica no objeto, ainda aciona o evento, mesmo estando desativado.

Isso é devido ao tipo do objeto ou algum cabeçalho? No HTML estou usando DTD strict.

Um outro meio para resolver seria abrir um modal na frente da tela inteira, impedindo o acesso a camada de baixo, mas quero evitar isso, por enquanto.

Comment: Daniel, conseguiste resolver este problema?

Comment: Desculpe Sérgio, esqueci de marcar a resposta. Fiquei na dpúvida entra a sua e a resposta do SneepS NinjA. No final fiz conforme o NinjA sugeriu, mas eu gostei mais do que você postou por isso vou marcar a sua como aceita. Vou usar essa técnica num próximo upgrade do sistema.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A ideia que me ocorre é usares uma espécie de "middleware" e fazeres todos os event handler passar por aí. Ai podes ter um objeto-flag com informação booleana para cada evento. Algo como:

```
(function(){ // com esta closure a variável flag não precisa ser global
    var flag = {
        click: false,
        mouseleave: false;
    };
    elA.addEventListener('click', middleware)
    elB.addEventListener('click', middleware)
    elA.addEventListener('mouseleave', middleware)
    elB.addEventListener('mouseleave', middleware)
    function middleware(e){
        // ver em baixo
    }
})();
```

e depois, dentro dessa função, ter a lógica que precisas para essa verificação:

```
function middleware(e){
    var tipoEvento = e.type;
    var elemento = this; // elemento que tem/disparou o event handler
    var alvo = e.target;

    // e a partir daqui podes ter uma lógica de if/else que detete o que precisas

    if (flag.click) foo();
    else bar();

    // etc...
}
```

Comment: pensou em fazer assim? https://jsfiddle.net/rvLa0u69/

Comment: @TobyMosque no teu exemplo `middleware` é um objeto e tem de ser uma função para poder ser usado como argumento para o event handler. Daqui a pouco saio do trabalho e vou completar a resposta e dar um exemplo para ficar completo.

Answer (score 2):

dentro de foo() pode ter uma variavel global que você habilita ou desabilita quando quiser, e quando foo() for chamado você faz um if verificando a variavel global

```
    flag_global = 0;

function foo(){

    if( flag_global == 0){ return 0; }
    ...
    ...
    ...
    return 1;
}

function habilitar(){ flag_global=1; }

function desabilitar(){ flag_global=0; }
```

Comment: Verdade, é o meio mais simples. Eu procurava algo mais "elegante", dentro dos recursos do JQuery ou algo adequado para o caso como um "desligar/ligar".  Acho que vou usar isso mesmo que é o mais óbvio.

Answer (score 0):

segue uma alternativa usando um eventHandler:

```js
var eventHandle  =  {
    flag: 0,
    elements: {
     input01: document.getElementById("input01"),
        input02: document.getElementById("input02"),
        input03: document.getElementById("input03"),
        monitorOn: document.getElementById("monitorOn"),
        monitorOff: document.getElementById("monitorOff")
    },
    init: function() {
        this.elements.input01.addEventListener("input", this, false);
     this.elements.input02.addEventListener("input", this, false);
     this.elements.input03.addEventListener("input", this, false);
        this.elements.monitorOn.addEventListener("click", this, false);
        this.elements.monitorOff.addEventListener("click", this, false);
    },    
    handleEvent: function(event) {
        //não entendo por que consigo acessar o input#input01 atraves do "input01" 
        //e não apenas pelo "this.elements.input01", 
        //alguem pode me esplicar a logica deste escopo?
        //console.log(input01, this.elements.input01)
        if (this.checkEvent(event, this.elements.input01, "input", 1)) {
            this.onInput01(event);
        }
        if (this.checkEvent(event, this.elements.input02, "input", 1)) {
            this.onInput02(event);
        }
        if (this.checkEvent(event, this.elements.input03, "input", 1)) {
            this.onInput03(event);
        }
        if (this.checkEvent(event, this.elements.monitorOn, "click", 0)) {
            this.onMonitorOnClick(event);
        }
        if (this.checkEvent(event, this.elements.monitorOff, "click", 1)) {
            this.onMonitorOffClick(event);
        }
    },
    checkEvent: function(event, element, type, flag) {
        return event.target == element && event.type == type && this.flag == flag;
    },
    onInput01: function(event) {
        console.log(event.target.value)
    },
    onInput02: function(event) {
        console.log(event.target.value)
    },
    onInput03: function(event) {
        console.log(event.target.value)
    },
    onMonitorOnClick: function(event) {
        this.flag = 1;
    },
    onMonitorOffClick: function(event) {
        this.flag = 0;
    }
};

eventHandle.init();
```

```html
<div>
    <input id="input01" type="text" />
</div>
<div>
    <input id="input02" type="text" />
</div>
<div>
    <input id="input03" type="text" />
</div>
<div>
    <input id="monitorOn" type="button" value="Ligar Monitor" />
</div>
<div>
    <input id="monitorOff" type="button" value="Desligar Monitor" />
</div>
```

No exemplo acima, caso o monitor estiver ligado, ele vai registrar qual quer alteração nos inputs.