# Resetar functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, funções

Em uma suposta página onde todo o conteúdo todo site é carregado em divs dinâmicas sem a necessidade refresh, ao fechar uma dessas divs é possível resetar a function que adicionou o conteúdo a essa div junto a todos os demais eventos / functions dentro dela? Ou o mais correto seria eu criar condições para saber se o elemento está ou não visível e então prosseguir com o restante das functions?

Comment: O que você chama de *resetar*?

Comment: Em uma div por exemplo que será carregado vídeo, vai ficar fazendo requisições ajax mandando o tempo de vídeo assistido, algumas teclas que tem suas funções padrões modificadas dentro da função, space, enter... após fechar gostaria que todos esses eventos criados por essa function fossem resetados e só voltassem a funcionar quando a function fosse chamada novamente

Comment: Você precisa desfazer tudo manualmente, incluindo remover ou esvaziar a tal div.

Comment: e colocar condições em todos os eventos criados que vão se repetir a cada x segundos enquanto essa div estiver visível?

Comment: Ou remover os eventos https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener

Comment: removeEventListener vai remover tudo que foi criado pela function e resetar as variáveis ou só os eventos?

Comment: `removeEventListener` precisa ser usado de um jeito muito específico. É melhor você [edit] a sua pergunta e incluir o código relevante (js e o HTML relevante)

Comment: Isso me lembrou uma pergunta similar que fiz há mais de 1 ano. Talvez pode ter alguma utilidade para o seu caso: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/81795/ativar-e-desativar-um-evento-sem-precisar-excluir-e-recriar-o-mesmo

Comment: Algumas soluções apresentadas na sua pergunta me servem bem @DanielOmine mas como você mesmo falou em sua pergunta "Eu esperava algo mais elegante do jQuery"